# Can I have a different android:label value and Play Store Title

Tags: android, google-play

I am making an app to help someone recover their phone if it's stolen. It runs as a background service that is started on boot completion.

On the phone I would like the app name to show up as "Nothing to See Here", but I would like the Google Play listing to have the name "Find Your Stolen Phone".

Can I set my `android:label="Nothing to See Here"` and then set the Play Store Title as `Find Your Stolen Phone`? If not is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: the play store name is set in the developer console not the app

Comment: OK, so it doesn't have to match up to what's declared in the APK then. That's what I wanted to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is yes !

Because the label indicates the name which is shown on the device launcher as app Name.

> A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default
>   label for each of the application's components. See the individual
>   label attributes for , , ,
>   , and  elements.  The label should be set as a
>   reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized like other
>   strings in the user interface. However, as a convenience while you're
>   developing the application, it can also be set as a raw string.

And the name it is shown as in the PlayStore is set in the developer console !